# weblogic version which compatibility with log4j 2.17.1

Tags: security, devops, weblogic, log4j2

what would be the compatible **weblogic** versions for the log-2.17.1. any Reference link is useful.

part of my research nowhere i found related solutions in the official sites

Answer (score 1):

It would be more the java version that weblogic runs on.  If it supports java 8 then you would be able to use log4j 2.17.1.    I think weblogic 12.1.3 onwards supports java 8.

Comment: WebLogic Server 12.1.3 supports Oracle JDK 8 until version 281
WebLogic server 12.2.1.3 supports Oracle JDK 8 until version 281
WebLogic server 12.2.1.4 supports Oracle JDK 8 until version 321
WebLogic server 14.1.1 supports Oracle JDK 8 until version 321 and Oracle JDK 11 until version 14